# Edit batch for MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I have a batch which took for input arguments, the file to be processed and a processing date.

The reader is of this type:

```
<bean id="adherentsItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" 
scope="step">
<property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['inputResource']}"/>
<property name="lineMapper" ref="adherentsLineMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="adherentsLineMapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
<property name="lineTokenizer" ref="adherentsLineTokenizer"/>
<property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="adherentsFieldSetMapper"/>
</bean>


<bean id="adherentsLineTokenizer" 
 class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
    <property name="names" value="xxx,xx,xxx,xxx,xxx"/>
</bean>
```

But, there has been a change. One of the input files can contain up to 45,000,000 lines !!
One of the ways to follow is to cut this file into 45 files of 1,000,000 lines (but if you have a solution to read a file of 45,000,000 lines, I'm interested). I therefore have to change my reader in order to read several .dat files as input. Here is my modification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="adherentsItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:dat/ExamResult*.dat" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
</bean>

<bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" 
scope="step">
    <property name="lineMapper" ref="adherentsLineMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="adherentsLineMapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
    <property name="lineTokenizer" ref="adherentsLineTokenizer"/>
    <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="adherentsFieldSetMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="adherentsLineTokenizer" 
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
    <property name="names" value="xxx,xx,xxx,xxx,xxx"/>
</bean>

<!-- Bean s'occupant de mapper les données avec les champs définis par le  adherentLineTokenizer -->
<bean id="adherentsFieldSetMapper"
      class="fr.cnamts.stau.batch.adherents.step.importadherents.reader.AdherentsFiledSetMapper"/>

</beans>
```

But with this configuration, the batch crashes as soon as I put two files in the input directory. Why ?
Another question how to keep the input parameter of the files (args [0]) when using MultiResourceItemReader?

Thank you for your leads and feedback.

Cdt,

Comment: `the batch crashes as soon as I put two files in the input directory. Why ? ` How does it crash? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Hello Mahmoud. I provided an answer just below.
The multiResourceItemReader + taskExecutor does not match. I am losing data.
I'm trying to set up the partitioning but I'm having a little trouble.
The idea would be for the big file to be read and then partitioned and each partition could handle 1 million lines. How to do it via xml configuration?
Thank you.

Comment: The FlatFileItemReader is not thread safe, so using it as a delegate of MultiResourceItemReader in a multi-threaded step is not correct. I have a similar example that splits a file and does a word count here: https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/master/issues/so53366710. However, it is configured in Java, I will let you adapt it to your XML config. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. I have trouble transposing to XML. I see the principle but I can't. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have advanced in problem. The input files had errors. It's OK, the two input files are taken into account. However, I had activated the taskExecutor tasklet to speed up processing.

```
        <step id="step_importAdherents">
        <!--<partition step="step1" partitioner="partitioner">
            <handler grid-size="2" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>-->
        <tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="20">
            <chunk  reader="adherentsItemReader"
                    processor="adherentsItemProcessor"
                    writer="adherentsItemWriter" commit-interval="1">
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="importAdherentsListener" />
                    <listener ref="readListener" />
                    <listener ref="writeListener" />
                </listeners>
            </chunk>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
<bean id="taskExecutor" 
class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
```

When I run the batch with this tasklet, all the data is not inserted (total of the two 24 files), either I have 13 or 7, it's random. If I remove this tasklet, I have the 24 records in the database. Why ?